# Linux: Disable permission to read for other users

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have a apache www folder, on Ubuntu machine. My current user 'joe' is the administrator. I added couple new users, but they can access www folder, how can I set permission to the folder, so a specific user can't access the folder (or he can read contents, but cannot open or modify any files)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example

```
find /www -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find /www -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;

chown -R joe /www
```

But be aware: the apache must run as joe to have still access to this directories and files.

Or you have to create a special group, give the directory via chown to this new group, change the chmod's to 660 and 770 and put the user joe into this new group. And the apache-user should be in this group too.